# Minimize the following function

Tags: calculus, statistics

I'm trying to find the value of $n_1$ which minimize the following function: $$Var(\overline{X}_{Str,n})=0.25\left(\frac{\sigma^2_1}{n_1} + \frac{\sigma^2_2}{20-n_1}\right )$$

I tried to solve the first order condition $\frac{\partial Var(\overline{X}_{Str,n})}{\partial n_1}=0$, but I find it difficult to solve. Can someone show me the right procedure or the steps to find the final solution?

I know that the final solution should be: $$n_1=20\frac{\sigma_1 }{\sigma _1+\sigma _2}$$

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For a function of the form $$f(x) = \frac{a^2}{x} + \frac{b^2}{c-x}$$
local extrema can be located by finding where $f'(x)=0$. This gives the condition
$$-\frac{a^2}{x^2} + \frac{b^2}{(c-x)^2} = 0$$
$$\left(\frac{b}{c-x} + \frac{a}{x}\right)\left(\frac{b}{c-x} - \frac{a}{x}\right)=0$$
You should be able to solve it from here. Note that in your case, $$a=\sigma_1,b=\sigma_2,c=20$$

Comment: with the condition $f'(x)=0$ can not located only local extrema, see $f(x)=x^3$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: My answer is a hint, not a full solution. And I didn't say $f'(x)=0$ is sufficient to guarantee a local extremum. The implication of my hint is that this condition is a necessary condition where $f$ is differentiable, so OP can locate candidates for the desired extremum. OP does have to do *some* work, after all.

Comment: yes i know that all and you know it but know it the OP?

Comment: @MPW *Don't give a child a fish but show him how to fish*; this is what you do and it is great ! Happy New Year !!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Let's allow OP to read my answer and try to arrive at the solution. If he has trouble, he can always comment and request additional help. I think it's **always** better to give hints before the full solution, so OP can work with the problem and gain something from  it. Simply giving a full solution teaches nothing.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Precisely! Thanks for the recognition. And may you have a happy new year as well!

Comment: @MPW yes i agree with you and also a happy new year with full of mathematics and health

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Thank you, and "mathy" new year to you as well ;)

Comment: @MPW math is my live thank you too

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Thanks, by the way I found an easiest way of resolution, starting form your second expression. In fact: $$\left [\frac{b^2}{(c-x)^2}   \right ]^{1/2}= \left [\frac{a^2}{x^2}  \right ]^{1/2}$$ $$\frac{b}{(c-x)}=\frac{a}{x}$$ Then utilizing the cross multiplication: $$xb=a(c-x)$$ And then from here it is easy to find the value of x. By the way I can't agree more on what you said above: it is always better to give hints than full solutions. Well said!

Comment: @1937HCAP: I guess that was intended for me? The comment was addressed to Sonnhard, but written by me. Glad you found the solution. Note that there are really two solutions, but you can discard one (why?). You left off the "$\pm$" when you took square roots, so you really get the same pair of solutions you get by setting each factor in my equation equal to zero.

Comment: @MPW Yeah, I'm really sorry I completely misread the comment above. Thank you for your help! By the way I'm not considering the negative result because the goal of the exercise was to find the minimum number of observations to minimize the variance of the expected value of a random variable (it is pointless to consider a number of observations that is smaller than zero).

Comment: Your analysis of the two solutions is correct. You should always consider both, then make a judgement based on the application. Good for you!